# Excel formula - calculate the highest team start position deducted from the highest team finish position

Tags: excel

Is there a excel formula that is able to calculate the highest team start position deducted from the highest team finish position and (if the result is positive) multiplied by 5 to a maximum of 50?

[image]

in the above example Team T's highest start position was 13th and there highest finish position was 9th so 4 places difference * 5 = 20 ( added to D10 and 0 in D2 can be either way round so the team score is only calculated once )

Thanks

Comment: By "highest" you seem to mean Team with letter "closest to the top" (that is row 1), but not itself, is that correct?  Also, please clarify how D2 is zero?

Comment: sorry for any confusion by highest i mean each team is identified by a letter and comprise of two entries, Team T had start position of 13th and 15th so selecting the highests start position 13th and the Team T finished with 9th and 11th, highest start for team T would be 13th and highest finish for team T would be 9th with 4 places between 9th and 13th. I added a 0 to the other team pair as i only need the points once for each team? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MINIFS():

```
=MIN(IF(C2=MINIFS(C:C,A:A,A2),MINIFS(B:B,A:A,A2)-MINIFS(C:C,A:A,A2),0)*5,50)
```

[image]

Comment: Elegant approach with the opening if condition, and the open-ended ranges (A:A, etc).  You only need to add one more outer MIN() for the max 50 condition.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for this, to eliminate the negative results would using a MAX like this me sutible? =MAX(0,MIN(IF(C2=MINIFS(C:C,A:A,A2),MINIFS(B:B,A:A,A2)-MINIFS(C:C,A:A,A2),0)*5,50),MIN(IF(C2=MINIFS(C:C,A:A,A2),MINIFS(B:B,A:A,A2)-MINIFS(C:C,A:A,A2),0)*5,50))

Comment: @DwayneDibbley yes.  that would do it.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A11,$A$1:A10,0)),MIN((MINIFS($B$2:$B$21,$A$2:$A$21,A11)-MINIFS($C$2:$C$21,$A$2:$A$21,A11))*5,50),0)
```

to break this down:

IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A11,$A$1:A10,0)) 
<== first well check to see if this If I've calculated this team, by trying to match against the team list, up to this point. Match() returns a numeric for a hit (already done ==> return zer0), or #NA (error) for a new (not already found) instance of the team.

MIN(        <= take the lessor of the next calculation or 50
     (MINIFS($B$2:$B$21,$A$2:$A$21,A11) <= Return the lowest MIN() START (B:B) where all A11's are found in the list A2:A21

```
  -   <= and deduct from
  MINIFS($C$2:$C$21,$A$2:$A$21,A11)) <=== <= Return the lowest MIN() FINISH (C:C) where all A11's are found in the list A2:A21

   *5   <==and multiply result by 5
```

,50)  <== or return 50 from MIN above)

,0) <= from if() above

[image]

Hope this works for you.